# How to use html hyperlink in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

It's it possible to use or replace  Check Something  to be a regular hyperlink in Swift?

I'm getting a wall of text in HTML format and I'm changing it to string, and this wall of text contains hyperlinks and I want to keep them inside and make it work in my iOS app as well.

Thats a example of html text:

```html
<p>Some title par</p><br>
<p>Text is here but contains <a href="page.com", target="_blank"> hyperlink </a> inside </p>
```

My func which turns it to a string:

```swift
    private func normalize(htmlText: String) -> String {

        func basicNormalize(htmlString: String) -> String {
            return htmlText
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "<br>", with: "\n")
                .replacingOccurrences(of: "&quot;", with: "\"")
        }

        guard let data = htmlText.data(using: .utf8) else {
            return basicNormalize(htmlString: htmlText)
        }

        let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
            .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
            .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]

        guard let attributedString = try? NSAttributedString(
            data: data,
            options: options,
            documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return basicNormalize(htmlString: htmlText)
        }
        return attributedString.string
    }
```

Output - current. (In desired I want to have URL stored and launched from "hyperlink" text)

```
Some title par

Text is here but contains hyperlink inside
```

I was looking for some solutions but most of them are outdated or just do not fit my case.

As you see the first part of getting rid of html tags work but how to keep hyperlink inside?

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for WKWebView (instead of converting text, display it in WKWEbView)

Comment: You can't, is you keep using in the end a `String`. A String is just a suite of "letters". You want a `NSAttributedString`. You can remove all the "effects" on it which aren't NSLinkAttribute, that's all.

Comment: @thiscommunityistoxic - actually I want to avoid using webview at all.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is just a suite of characters, so it can't have a "link" embedded in it. You need to use a `NSAttributedString` that will allow to have on needed parts a link.
You can remove all the others attributes:

```
private func normalize(htmlText: String) -> NSAttributedString {

    func basicNormalize(htmlString: String) -> String {
        return htmlText
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "<br>", with: "\n")
            .replacingOccurrences(of: "&quot;", with: "\"")
    }

    guard let data = htmlText.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return NSAttributedString(string: basicNormalize(htmlString: htmlText))
    }

    let options: [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey: Any] = [
        .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
        .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
    ]

    guard let attributedString = try? NSMutableAttributedString(
        data: data,
        options: options,
        documentAttributes: nil) else {
            return NSAttributedString(string: basicNormalize(htmlString: htmlText))
        }
    print("Before:\n\(attributedString)")
    attributedString.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length),
                                         options: []) { attributes, subrange, stop in
        let attributesToRemove = attributes.filter { $0.key != .link }
        attributesToRemove.forEach {
            attributedString.removeAttribute($0.key, range: subrange)
        }
    }
    print("Result:\n\(attributedString)")
    return attributedString
}
```

To test, I added some other "effects", like bold, underline, italic, etc.

```
let htmlString = """
    <p>Some title par</p><br>
    <p>Text is here <b>but</b> contains <a href="page.com", target="_blank"> hyperlink </a> inside </p>
    """

_ = normalize(htmlText: htmlString)
```

Output:

```
$>Before:
Some title {
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}par{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrikethrough = 1;
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}Text {
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}is{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
} {
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}here{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Italic 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x101045410, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
} {
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1007b94b0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}but{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Bold 12.00 pt. P [] (0x10121ce80) fobj=0x101046990, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
} contains {
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x10121ce80) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}hyperlink {
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0.933333 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x1012457c0) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSLink = "applewebdata://59096E66-D4AD-499A-911D-DE31AB022E61/page.com";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0.933333 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}inside 
{
    NSColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "\"Times-Roman 12.00 pt. P [] (0x101246370) fobj=0x10103dc90, spc=3.00\"";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation YES, HeaderLevel 0 LineBreakStrategy 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}
$> Result:
Some title par

Text is here but contains {
}hyperlink {
    NSLink = "applewebdata://59096E66-D4AD-499A-911D-DE31AB022E61/page.com";
}inside 
{
}
```